# Howto build Interbase plugin for Qt by MinGW

Tags: qt, plugins, mingw

I want to build Interbase plugin for Qt using MinGW toolchain.
According to [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qibase-plugin-on-windows), I can do it only by MSVC, but I need MinGW... So, I wrote this .cmd file

```
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\4.8.0-minGW
set PATH=C:\Qt\4.8.0-minGW\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin
set QMAKESPEC=win32-g++

set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\Program Files\Borland\InterBase\SDK\include
set LIB=%LIB%;c:\Program Files\Borland\InterBase\SDK\lib_ms
qmake -o Makefile ibase.pro
mingw32-make.exe
pause
```

and ran it from `c:\Qt\4.8.0-minGW\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase\`. Whole output is very long, but there's many similar lines, that's why I'll show only one of them and the final lines

```
tmp/obj/debug_shared/qsql_ibase.o: In function `ZN12QIBaseDriver24qHandleEventNo
tificationEPv':
C:\Qt\4.8.0-minGW\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase/../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_i
base.cpp:1845: undefined reference to `isc_event_counts'
C:\Qt\4.8.0-minGW\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase/../../../sql/drivers/ibase/qsql_i
base.cpp:1864: undefined reference to `isc_que_events'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

Could you tell me, how should I achive my target. Thank you.

P.S. I googled a lot and saw this quiestion - [Compiling InterBase support in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038649/compiling-interbase-support-in-qt) - but there wasn't exact answer what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it !!!

The problem was in header file `ibase.h` from Interbase's SDK. There was following lines:

```
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN32)) || \
    (defined(__BORLANDC__) && (defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__OS2__)))
...
#define  ISC_EXPORT    __stdcall
...
```

Macro `ISC_EXPORT` was not defined and all function's declarations was wrong. When I changed these lines in the following way:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
...
#define  ISC_EXPORT    __stdcall
...
```

plugin was successfuly build