# Compiling ibase driver for Qt 5.5.1 (msvc2010)

Tags: windows, qt, firebird, interbase

I need ibase driver for Qt to work with Firebird databases.
I have installed:

- Windows 7 SP1 32 bit
- QT 5.5.1-0 (msvc2010 32bit)
- Source components/ Essentials (5.5.1-0)
- Firebird 2.1.5 32 bit

I try make it as [an official site described](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qibase), but replace

```
cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/interbase/include" "LIBS+=-lfbclient" ibase.pro
```

with it:
make library fbclient.dll in c:\windows\system32

```
C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\bin\instclient i f
```

than compile driver ibase:

```
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake INCLUDEPATH+='C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include'" "LIBS+=-LC:\Windows\system32\fbclient.dll" ibase.pro
Project ERROR: Cannot load qmodule.pri!
Error processing project file: ibase.pro
```

Before i try compile it with qt 5.1.0 (mingw32), and no errors.
But with qt 5.1.0 (mingw32) i can't linking fbclient.dll (that, probably, compiled with MSVS). Because of the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038649/compiling-interbase-support-in-qt) compilers (firebird compiled with MSVC, and was with qt mingw) decided to switch to QT 5.5.1 (with msvc2010).

If i run qmake with **-d**, than

```
    C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+='C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_1\include'" "LIBS+=-LC:\Windows\system32\fbclient.dll" i base.pro -d 
DEBUG 1: Resetting dir to: C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase
DEBUG 1: visiting file C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: evaluating test function "load"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: calling built-in load(qt_build_config)
DEBUG 1: visiting file C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: NOT
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: evaluating test function "contains"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: calling built-in contains(QMAKE_INTERNAL_INCLUDED_FILES, .*qmodule\\.pri)
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: test function returned false
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: taking 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:12: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:13: QMAKE_QT_MODULE := C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: NOT 
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: evaluating test function "exists"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: calling built-in exists(C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri)
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: test function returned false
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: OR
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: NOT
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: skipped test function "include"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: taking 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:14: entering block
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: evaluating test function "error"
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: calling built-in error("Cannot load qmodule.pri!")
Project ERROR: Cannot load qmodule.pri!
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, function status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: finished 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: finished 'then' branch
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:15: aborting block, status: error
DEBUG 1: C:/Qt/5.5/Src/qtbase/.qmake.conf:1: aborting block, function status: error
Error processing project file: ibase.pro
```

This file

QMAKE_QT_MODULE := C:/work/build/PADDING/mkspecs/qmodule.pri

doesn't exist in my system, inplace, i think, must be

```
c:\Qt\5.5\msvc2010\mkspecs\qmodule.pri
```

The values in the paths of system variables Qt suggest that something is not configured, or configured wrong:

```
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake -query
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_DATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:C:/work/build/PADDING/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:C:/work/build/PADDING/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:C:/work/build/PADDING/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_INSTALL_BINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:C:/work/build/PADDING/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/plugins
QT_INSTALL_IMPORTS:C:/work/build/PADDING/imports
QT_INSTALL_QML:C:/work/build/PADDING/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:C:/work/build/PADDING/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:C:/work/build/PADDING/examples
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:C:/work/build/PADDING/examples
QT_HOST_PREFIX:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_HOST_DATA:C:/work/build/PADDING
QT_HOST_BINS:C:/work/build/PADDING/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:C:/work/build/PADDING/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_XSPEC:win32-msvc2010
QMAKE_VERSION:3.0
QT_VERSION:5.5.1
```

Now i think about reinstall QT clenly.
But what i can check/try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think a clean install QT solved the problem. 
So we put the MS Visual Studio 2010 Express SP1 (SP1 necessarily), QT 5.1.1 (msvc2010), Src/Essentials. Also to be Firebird. I used the 2.5.5 version in the zip file and unzip it into C:\QT\firebird255_32. After unpacking also took to copy the file C:\QT\firebird255_32\lib\fbclient_ms.lib and call it C:\QT\ firebird255_32\lib\gds32_ms.lib.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=C:/QT/firebird255_32/include" "LIBS+=-LC:/QT/firebird255_32/lib" ibase.pro
C:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\ibase>nmake
```

If all goes well, then in the folder c:\Qt\5.5\Src\qtbase\plugins\ sqldrivers \ files will appear:

qsqlibase.dll qsqlibase.exp qsqlibase.lib qsqlibased.dll qsqlibased.exp qsqlibased.ilk qsqlibased.lib qsqlibased.pdb

To be copied to the folder c:\Qt\5.5\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers.
Since the main objective was successful compilation, these libraries have not been tested in applications. You should also note that I used Firebird version is not installed in the system (may be problems with the transfer of the application). [Here](http://www.cyberforum.ru/post5231947.html), too, is an example of a successful build of this driver, and even the C compiler mingw. Perhaps, and it did not have to use it msvc2010.